# How do I make a frame with no title bar but with resize borders?

Tags: python, wxpython

I want to have no title bar but resizable borders.
When I try this code a little white border is created at the top of the frame:

```py
class MyFrame(wx.MiniFrame):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyFrame, self).__init__(
            None, -1, '', (100,100), (200,200), wx.NO_BORDER^wx.RESIZE_BORDER
            )

        self.pnl =wx.Panel(self , -1,(0,0), (200,200), )
        self.pnl.SetBackgroundColour(wx.RED)

        self.closeButton = wx.Button(self.pnl, 1000, 'close',(10,10) ,(50,30))
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.quit, self.closeButton)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't declare NO_BORDER and RESIZE_BORDER by definition you can't have a re-sizable border if there isn't a border.
The closest I can get, others may know better, is to have a minimal border that can be re-sized.

```
import wx

class MyFrame(wx.MiniFrame):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyFrame, self).__init__(
            None, -1, '', (100,100), (200,200), style=wx.RESIZE_BORDER)

        self.pnl =wx.Panel(self , -1,(0,0), (200,200), )
        self.pnl.SetBackgroundColour(wx.RED)

        self.closeButton = wx.Button(self.pnl, 1000, 'close',(10,10) ,(50,30))
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.quit, self.closeButton)

    def quit(self,event):
        self.Destroy()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App(False)
    frame = MyFrame()
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

[image]

Note the grabber in the bottom right-hand corner. That allows you to re-size the window

Comment: thanks ,i'm trying to implement resizing by my self, is there a good reference for that?

Comment: In my humble opinion, you are attempting to re-invent the wheel!

Comment: well i agree with you if i will do the same functionality, but what i'm doing is just creating configurable  title bar because  default title bar has rigid properties like color , buttons  in it , so  doing this is just by providing  a frame with no title bar  and adding my  title bar with all functionality icon , moving ,resizing ..etc.

Comment: There is a reason for that. Notably to ensure consistency of look and feel for the entire desktop. Still, I'm intrigued, let me know how you get on.

Answer (score 1):

You may find this useful.

```
import wx
class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(None, -1, pos=(300, 150), size=(320, 250),style=wx.NO_BORDER)
        self.panel = wx.Panel(self)
        self.text = wx.StaticText(self.panel, -1, label="Left click mouse, move and release\nor Move the window")
        self.panel.Bind(wx.EVT_LEFT_DOWN, self.OnDown)
        self.panel.Bind(wx.EVT_LEFT_UP, self.OnUp)
        self.panel.Bind(wx.EVT_MOTION, self.OnDrag)
        self.Show()

    def OnDown(self, event):
        x, y = event.GetPosition()
        print("Click coordinates: X=",x," Y=",y)

    def OnUp(self, event):
        x, y = event.GetPosition()
        print("Release coordinates: X=",x," Y=",y)

    def OnDrag(self, event):
        if not event.Dragging():
            return
        x, y = event.GetPosition()
        obj = event.GetEventObject()
        sx, sy = obj.GetScreenPosition()
        self.Move(sx+x,sy+y)

app = wx.App()
window = MyFrame()
app.MainLoop()
```